# zxing camera is not working with Android API 4.0.3?

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

My application is using Zxing camera,

It is working fine but when I try to open this application in device with Android API 4.0.3 then it is crashing automatically from CameraManager.java

```
if (camera == null) {
  camera = Camera.open();
  //camera = Camera.open(getFrontFacingCameraId());      
  if (camera == null) {
    throw new IOException();
  }
}
```

Logcat shows following error :

```
    at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:129)
```

Can anybody help me what can I do?

Comment: You might consider posting the entire stack trace.

Comment: If you mean the IOException is thrown, it's because the device has an error in its camera driver. The API does not allow null to be returned, and devices that do are usually rooted devices with corrupted settings.